# Who is causing Device or resource busy when mounting a block device?

Tags: linux, block-device

I have plugged a HDD with some partitions to a Linux box, but when I try to mount them it fails:

```
[root@il ~]# mount -oro /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
```

It's not already mounted (at least, the mount is not visible in the current root):

```
[root@il ~]# grep sdb /proc/mounts
[root@il ~]#
```

If I copy sdb1 contents to a file using `dd` and mount it as a loop device **it mounts just fine.**. (I also managed to circumvent this by mapping an intermediate loop device to sdb1 instead of copying)

```
[root@il ~]# mount -oro,loop /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1
[root@il ~]#
```

So I wrote a small program to check:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc < 2) {
                return 1;
        }
        int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_EXCL);
        printf("%d\n", fd);
        return 0;
}
```

And as I expected, the program cannot open the partitions from that HDD:

```
[root@il ~]# ./excl /dev/sdb1
-1
# another unmounted NTFS partition
[root@il ~]# ./excl /dev/md124p6
3
```

How to figure out who is preventing exclusive access to the disk? I'm looking for a generic tool better than `lsof` because `lsof` won't print the files open for loop devices or by dmraid or mdraid.

```
[root@il ~]# dmraid -s
ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set "ddf1_4c5349202020202010000055000000004711471100000a28" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
*** Group superset .ddf1_disks
--> *Inconsistent* Subset
name   : ddf1_4c5349202020202010000055000000004711471100000a28
size   : 623046656
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : inconsistent
subsets: 0
devs   : 1
spares : 0
*** Group superset isw_ebaifefjbf
--> Subset
name   : isw_ebaifefjbf_Volume0
size   : 976783360
stride : 256
type   : stripe
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

_

```
[root@il ~]# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0   100M  0 loop
sda            8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk
└─md124        9:124  0 465,8G  0 raid0
  ├─md124p1  259:0    0   9,8G  0 part  /media/realboot
  ├─md124p2  259:1    0     1K  0 part
  ├─md124p5  259:2    0 195,3G  0 part  /media/distrpart
  ├─md124p6  259:3    0  19,5G  0 part
  ├─md124p7  259:4    0   3,7G  0 part  [SWAP]
  ├─md124p8  259:5    0   155G  0 part  /.sxbackup
  ├─md124p9  259:6    0  81,7G  0 part  /media/ARCHLINUXOLD
  └─md124p10 259:7    0 782,6M  0 part
sdb            8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdb1         8:17   0   100M  0 part
└─sdb2         8:18   0   297G  0 part
sdc            8:32   0 232,9G  0 disk
└─md124        9:124  0 465,8G  0 raid0
  ├─md124p1  259:0    0   9,8G  0 part  /media/realboot
  ├─md124p2  259:1    0     1K  0 part
  ├─md124p5  259:2    0 195,3G  0 part  /media/distrpart
  ├─md124p6  259:3    0  19,5G  0 part
  ├─md124p7  259:4    0   3,7G  0 part  [SWAP]
  ├─md124p8  259:5    0   155G  0 part  /.sxbackup
  ├─md124p9  259:6    0  81,7G  0 part  /media/ARCHLINUXOLD
  └─md124p10 259:7    0 782,6M  0 part
```

Comment: Your system is F*d because partitions of `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc` are mounted on the same mountpoints.

Comment: @waltinator no, they’re part of an `md` device.